# How to force screen resolution on Windows 98 under VirtualBox?

Tags: display, resolution, windows-98

I have been preparing Windows 98 for use and one thing that bugs me is too low a screen resolution.

So, I was told to install SciTech Display Doctor and switched to their display driver. I also have the monitor recognized as CyberVision C112 and now I can set the resolution to whatever I want, as long as I am using the SciTech display driver.

However, I don't get an option for 1366 x 768, which is my native resolution. I can set the colors to 32-bit, which I did, but this doesn't do anything.

I have tried changing `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Display\Settings\Resolution` to `1366,768`, but I get an error when I restart:

> There is a problem with your display settings. The adapter type is incorrect, or **the current settings do not work with your hardare**.

Is there a way to force the resolution to 1366x768 on Windows 98?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VBEMP, it supports 1366x768. No 2D/3D acceleration whatsover, but as long as you don't run any games, you should be fine. Also use it in 16 bit colour mode, it's slightly faster.

You'll find VBEMP here:
http://www.navozhdeniye.narod.ru/vbe9x.htm